# Is there a way infer the return value type of a callback instead of pass the generic parameter

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I had written a react custom hook like this:

```
import { useEffect, useCallback, useState } from 'react';

const apis = {
    async getUser(id: string): Promise<{ id: string; name: string }> {
        return { id, name: 'test' }
    }
}

type UseAsyncResponseStatus = 'idle' | 'pending';
type AsyncFn = (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>;
type UnboxPromise<T extends Promise<any>> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : never;
function useApiQuery<Api extends AsyncFn = AsyncFn>(fn: (...params: any) => ReturnType<Api>, params?: any) {
    const [status, setStatus] = useState<UseAsyncResponseStatus>('idle');
    const [value, setValue] = useState<UnboxPromise<ReturnType<Api>> | null>(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState<Error | null>(null);

    const execute = useCallback(async (_params: any) => {
        try {
            const res = await fn(_params);
            setValue(res);
        } catch (err) {
            setError(err as Error)
        } finally {
            setStatus('idle')
        }
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        execute(params)
    }, [execute, JSON.stringify(params)])

    return { execute, value, status, error }
}

const getUserQuery = useApiQuery<typeof apis.getUser>((id) => {
    return apis.getUser(String(id));
}, '1')
getUserQuery.value?.name // infer the value type based on API response
```

By now, it works fine if I pass the generic parameter to the `useApiQuery`, I can get the correct type of the API response. I have many hooks use this hook like this:

```
const useGetUserQuery = (id) => useApiQuery<typeof apis.getUser>((id) => {
    return apis.getUser(String(id));
}, id)

const useGetUsersQuery = () => useApiQuery<typeof apis.getUsers>(apis.getUsers);

// ...
```

I found it a little repetitive, I have to pass the generic parameter for each hook. Is there a way that TS can infer the return value type of the `callback` passed in `useApiQuery` internally, so that I don't need to pass generic parameters like `typeof apis.getUser` anymore? If I don't pass the generic parameter, the `getUserQuery.value` is `any` type which is not expected.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMCiAzb6DGMANChgMICGANlQEYX4DWJa6AyjBTOnAL5zYoEEHADkUdAxiiA3ACg5+CADtU8CmGCo4AXkRy4huBVQBPZfjgBzdDACqGKAApgAEwBccNVGDKrASk8ABSEQLXQAHiQ3T29fKxk4ZQoQdFiYHz8+AD59I3y4CRhkKGVEODcSZNTPUW41UT4DI145VrkYUzAeB3QAQTMLACV0VEhVdk5i7T1RNyp0RoAfMW7lV3jZDq6eAfN8ADEyvScAOnOKKCtUTwplUwBtAF1-XVyQ4XCIu9Ns+U7unA7MpaBAAB4fMIYCIAFTg6DB3HW2khXx+2VyejhCKRrhRoS+vjwUCBuQA-EC4J5lOgAG7oKDybDICwwYAqUj9TQARWQDNMET6mnhiPQyLgewsR10EsGh2U2Sc2GUnjO5zAlxSN2M91eOlyI2KpRhO0FmmyJA1UC1ZNuuryRiUqngDzUXDQJAwMA47tQTxlrB93AivUl+BGYxUGCDaEVc1cC1E-nk+SdajgD1p1D5ntsADVs+h-XpA1NIsDQRCCdDDSVlCbumbgBi4CtlMgaIr2zRk81DGmXQyhFBczBMFBh8XOUHIuPh62kh2qF2l72+3AByKCMhuAHyNQ6AxGE4TPs4E4APpWrV20x63IIdf5DKmB0FAqbiQzYwAdwowHgZVL2vEBUF7d93y9AsqD5Jwv3AiD+HwLh8AAC3PIdXkfCCCi9OdoCcIdjG0fCoH8J8WgEXwD1fbCcKML0Y1QJx40TcicNafJeBIZ5yPXVgcDwQgnCce83wKBFt24JwQLA9duIzST8B3dASAAKTYAB5AA5U44j8YBsFMGTNVA-wXgUfIijrcolJUkgsxg1SvCmD14QnaAmnaTcbHsRxeX5PcuWAAKoAFAF0AgbBjE0VBTl83ooEVFxXDEujDGs0oYq0eLbESpwOEyKwUv8XsFNEABGJM5AS-y+TC05HL5MlTmqHgAHp2oqZRiTgGBUJ4JqeAiuB6AwVw4A5PoggASUKUZxgwIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a type parameter directly for the value instead. You can also add one for the parameters to get type checking on those too:

```
function useApiQuery<TValue, TParams extends any[]>(fn: (...params: TParams) => Promise<TValue>, ...params: TParams) {
    const [status, setStatus] = useState<UseAsyncResponseStatus>('idle');
    const [value, setValue] = useState<TValue | null>(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState<Error | null>(null);

    const execute = useCallback(async (..._params: TParams) => {
        try {
            const res = await fn(..._params);
            setValue(res);
        } catch (err) {
            setError(err as Error)
        } finally {
            setStatus('idle')
        }
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        execute(...params)
    }, [execute, JSON.stringify(params)])

    return { execute, value, status, error }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMCiAzb6DGMANChgMICGANlQEYX4DWJa6AyjBTOnAL5zYoEEHADkUdAxiiA3ACg5+CADtU8CmGCo4AXkRy4huBVQBPZfjgBzdDACqGKKgAUASgBccAApCQW9AA8AIJQUBSmAUjAACaealDAylYycMoUIOhxMAlJfAB8efpGxXASMMhQynAA2lGxYgCMoiRpGZ6i3GqifAC6Bka8RP2GJuaWNvaOzjFZOVYe3r7+kXAzcPGJyanpmevZm-lFJYZlFVV1LTvtndJ8w3e8CjCmYDwO6EFmFgBK6KiQqnYnHK2j0ohiVHQ3QAPmJXspoptZApsMgLDBgCpSB9NABFZDoKARAAqADVqASSMSvBQwiBtOgAB7cBHaCjKUzVHp5ZzYZSeZwAOmFYFp6VQnmpYvprl0hR8wmWZIp6DyJGFgtFdIlcCl2tlCHuSlU8Gqai4aBIGBgHAtqB6umxtu4AXenzGv3+KgwzrQPPB0Uholc8mKxrUNQAbiqrbZyVQCQ69KxnYFlQmeLDlMgaDzszQQ0bvabCUIoLGYJhQtAk07gYEq2W4Fmc1Q863C0WTXAmQRkNxHaxKDR6ExnKMLHAhcKAPpa8WSmn6uVHY7ZUyr45GcPwCSg4wAdwowHgfOngrn0tQha3JWt8YJzj3N63-HwXHwAAsp6WDfdb9ajbQM4pbGNoQFQK4-4DAIiTUFQG6GrexTWr6LgBkGUG3o8xSDDUPRQfcrA4HghDOG4K5IVuvb4P26DnvOMr3Hh1Q0XRJAAFJsAA8gAcoKGxJMA2CmM4jHXgRCjFKclSID2jJ9twJDRhmVrApaPbVlADwKDu1i2O8UD4oSG7JhgQR4gSRLkTEso6IUVEnLYZzGJoqCChMhnOBwczTNEriFnhohNFBnmOMZRKCipBIAPyCq0PAAPSJasyh4NpMCfjw0U8M8rxwPQGDRHAWJBF4ACSpR-ACGC6cW2IAOIGY4qARaZU52YUrAWcAbXjm5HnNYS14yEAA)

Comment: Thanks. It's what I want, but how does this work? It seems you didn't do any infer operation manually. You added an extra generic parameter and removed the generic parameter for `useApiQuery`, then it works.

Comment: I used the implicit inference in generic functions. The problem with your approach is that `T` was used only in `ReturnType<T>` and that wasn't a usage TS could infer anything from. You can get part of `T` from knowing it's return type bit not all of it, and it's just something TS will not try to do.